# IE9 element with text + floated right element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have an issue with an link-element that has a right-floated icon next to it. In FF/Chrome everything looks good, but in IE9 the text is at the bottom of the container, not vertically aligned.

```
<a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="login">
   Login <span class="icon-login"></span>
</a>

.login {
   line-height: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   margin-top: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   float: right;
}

.icon-login {
   display: inline-block;
   line-height: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   float: right;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

How it's supposed to look (the green is the beginning of the icon)
[image]

IE9
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a `float` issue.

Try wrapping the `Login` text inside a `div` and `float` that to the `left`.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid adding extra markup, but it seems this is the only solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use someling like below.

```
<a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="login">
   Login 
</a>

.login {
   line-height: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   margin-top: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   float: right;
   background: url(icon-login.png) right center;
   padding-right:40px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I'd prefer using the same markup for icons that we use throughout the site. Thanks though!